# Unified MVC Controller Routing in Asp.Net 5

Tags: url-routing, asp.net-core

During my working in ASP.NET 5, I am confused in some of the unified controller concepts. Please show me what I doing wrong.

In ASP.NET 5 the same controller is used for MVC and WebApi with only the difference of Routing attribute defined above a Web Api controller. My thoughts is that the "Route" attribute is only used to define a route. But there has been some occurances that defining "Route" attribute at the top is specifing a controller to be a Web Api controller.

In Startup.cs, I have the following routing configurations.

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapWebApiRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{id?}");
        });
```

In Home Controller, there is "HttpGet" action for accepting WebApi `get` request, but it cannot be called without "Route" attribute, however the routing for the web api is already defined in the startup class.

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }

    //[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

And in Values controller, "About" action can't be accessed as the call to "/values/about" will give an error `not found`. And "/api/values/about" will redirected to the "Get" action.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller {
    public IActionResult About() {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }

    // GET: api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get() {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

But although I have specified the web api route in startup.cs file, I cant access the "/api/home" path. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I can't find a question in what you have written. Could please clarify?

Comment: My question is that, i have specified the web api route in startup.cs file, but i cant access the "/api/home" path

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing different routing methods.

Because the controllers are unified, you do not have to specify a route for webapi and another one for MVC.

The MapWebApiRoute function is only for backwards compatibility with code written for the older WebApi 2 ASP.NET.

If you want to use the convention based routing, you can just leave the UseMvc empty like this:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

For a thorough explanation of the different options, please see this useful blogpost: [ASP.NET 5 Deep Dive: Routing](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing).

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353866/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-controller-and-web-api-controller-in-asp-net) about the non-existing differences between MVC and WebApi Controllers in ASP.NET 5.

Comment: Thanks but this is very confusing. Routing module should not be mixed with the mvc and web api controllers. Both are very different concepts. Just adding a "Route" attribute should not convert a mvc action to a web api.

Comment: Well, as you mentioned, MVC and WebApi are merged in ASP.NET 5. See also http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/migration/migratingfromwebapi2.html.

Comment: I think that even after merging them both the api should have been supported and routing should be an separate. Adding annotation like [HTTPGET] should add web api action. And adding a route attribute should only define a route to the action.

Comment: Please see also my edit with an extra question on this subject.