# How to add Web API controller to an existing ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I created a project using the default ASP.NET Core MVC template. I would like to also create a RESTful API under `/api/{Controller}`. I added a new Web API controller (standard Web API controller class template) but I can't call it. I get an error saying that the page cannot be found. I tried adding a route in *Startup.cs* but it doesn't do anything:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(name: "api", template: "api/{controller=Admin}");
});
```

EDIT:

Like I said, it's all default templates. Here's the Web API Controller that I added:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{                
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    [HttpPut("{id}")]
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, im not on my home pc, so i may be wrong, but i dont think you need to add a new route for API. I think you just inherit from the APIController base class, and derive you're own from it. then MVC should do the routing for you. At this point, in your routing, the only thing you have is your default routing, and MVC will handle the API routing for you.

Comment: That's what I imagined, yet navigating to http://localhost:27891/api/Admin results in ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api
Scroll about halfway down to the ProductsController. It inherits from ApiController, not from controller.

Comment: That's old. They merged Controller and ApiController so now there's no real difference between the two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353866/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-controller-and-web-api-controller-in-asp-net?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating to the latest version of ASP.NET Core, v2.0.1 (the one that needs VS2017), the problem resolved itself. I think it was probably a bug or shortcoming in the old version.

Answer (score 11):

Two things.

First, when using convention-based routing, more specific routes should come before more generic routes to avoid route conflicts.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "api", template: "api/{controller=Admin}");
    routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Secondly, you are already using attribute routing on the controller so should have been able to route to the controller except for the fact that you do not have a routing template on the controller that would accept `/api/{Controller}`

That would require a default route.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AdminController : Controller {
 
    [HttpGet("")] //Matches GET api/admin <-- Would also work with [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")] //Matches GET api/admin/5
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {
        return Ok("value");
    }    

    //...other code removed for brevity
}
```

Comment: My first intention was to not touch the routes in app.UseMvc. However, out of the box, it doesn't work. [Route("api/[controller]")] is not enough. I did follow your suggestion and added the specific route before the generic one, just as above. If I try to navigate to https://localhost:27891/api/Admin it still doesn't work. Surprisingly, if I go to https://localhost:27891/[WHATEVER] it triggers the Get() method in AdminController and passes [WHATEVER] as an argument. This is really weird.

Answer (score 11):

I had luck doing this with v3.1:

Add Folder **Controllers** to the project. Add **Controller**, named TestController, to the folder.
Then add the following to the Startup.cs:

```
services.AddControllers();
```

to

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddControllers();
    }
```

and:

```
endpoints.MapControllers();
```

to

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Then I was able to call /api/Test.

Comment: This worked for me! Using my existing project, I created the template dot net core API project and copied the controller and class over, and these two lines of code were the only other things missing.

Comment: Worked for me in dotnetcore v5.0

Comment: you deserve 1 million upvotes holy crap. better than MS documentation. worked for me in .net5 as well

Answer (score 8):

If someone still have problem in adding webapi to .net core MVC, just inserting `[ApiController]` and `[Route("api/[controller]")]` attributes before class solves the problem:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ListController
{ ... }
```

I didn't added a route mapping in `Startup.cs` and still working well. The version of .net that I am using is 2.1.402

Answer (score 0):

Try setting name to "Admin"

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Admin",
                template: "api/{controller=Admin}");
        });
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The documentation says that the name of the route is not important, except for URL generation.

Answer (score 0):

Running existing .net core MVC:

[image: 1]

In order to add api controllers to existing .net core 6 mvc application,
Open Program.cs file,
add following codes:

```
//for apis
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.MapRazorPages();
endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Now go ahead and add a new controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    //endpoint: http://localhost:5207/api/test/strings
    [HttpGet("strings")]
    public IActionResult TestMethod()
    {
        return Ok(new string[]{ 
        "23", "24"});
    }
}
```

Testing Endpoint here

[image: 2]

This works for me in .net core 6

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This answer was already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60667151) 2 years ago. Please read al the other answers before posting a new one. Duplicate answers don't add any value to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to call https://localhost:7052/api/TranslationsJS/GetAll but I got 404 not found.

So my issue was that I had a typo in action. I defined a route name instead route template(path).

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TranslationsJSController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "GetAll")] // this didn't work because it is route name
    [HttpGet("GetAll")] // this worked because it is route template(path)
    public ActionResult<Dictionary<string, string>> GetAll()
    {
        var resourceSet = TranslationsJS.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        var translationsJs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
        {
            translationsJs.Add(entry.Key.ToString(), entry.Value.ToString());
        }
        return translationsJs;
    }
}
```

In program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

...

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#route-name

https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2017/02/generating-links-using-route-names-in.html